# which algorithm do maple use to calculate summation from zero to infinity

Tags: algorithms, generating-functions, maple

when calculating generating function, there is a need to do summation of ,

```
summation(f(x)*z^n/n!, n=0..infinity)
```

what algorithm do maple use to do this awesome work?

Comment: Awesome indeed, I have no idea although I'd bet that it tries to take out of the sum as many factors as possible and then try to recognize some "known" results.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean `f(x)` (where `x` is a function of neither `z` nor `n`) rather than `f(z)` or `f(z,n)`?!

If you really mean f(x) then the result is just `f(x)*exp(z)`, the computation of which is not especially awesome.

To make the question interesting let's suppose that you actually meant,

```
`sum( f(z,n)*z^n/n!, n=0..infinity )`
```

where `f(z,n)` is an explicit expression and not just some function call of unknown `f`.

The help-page for [SumTools](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=sumtools) (which `sum` calls) mentions that Gosper's algorithm for indefinite summation and Zeilberger's algorithm are its principal methods. And you can find quite a lot about them via google. See [this](http://www.mathematik.uni-kassel.de/~koepf/hyper.html), perhaps.

If you want to see Maple at work on a particular example then you can step through most of it in the Maple debugger or you can adjust various reporting mechanisms so as to get more verbose computations. Eg,

```
restart:
infolevel[sum]:=6: infolevel[rsolve]:=6: infolevel[LREtools]:=6:
trace(SumTools:-DefiniteSum:-ClosedForm):
trace(`sum/hypergeom`):
trace(`sum/hypergeom/separate`):
trace(`sum/hypergeom/term`):

sum(n^7/n!,n=1..infinity);

sum(sin(n)/n!,n=1..infinity);
```

Yet another mechanism is to set `printlevel` high (say, 25) but doing so may just producing a flood of output that you find confusing.

Your example's index's upper value was `infinity`. But for upper index value `K`, say, the code can go through [LRETools](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LREtools) and so perhaps see the reference at the bottom of [this](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LREtools/polysols) page.